# Greatest perimeter polygon on a geoboard

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, polygons

A physical geoboard is an organized set pegs that are distributed in a grid pattern which sits on (or is a part of) a thin rectangular base. Different sized Rubber bands can wrap around the pegs of geoboard, which can form a large number of patterns and shapes. An example of this is shown in the picture below.

[image: geoboard picture]

When I was a kid I had a computer program that was a digital version of a geoboard. The program had a square grid of nodes. The grid was ten nodes by ten nodes. Nodes on the grid could be connected by line segments.

One feature of the digital geoboard is that if a closed shape was formed by line segments, the perimeter of the shape could be measured. One unit on the geoboard was the distance between two adjacent points in the horizontal or vertical direction.

[Here](https://youtu.be/P-kJ1C1rTZ4) is a YouTube video of the program.

One thing I tried to do during the time when I had the program was to find the largest perimeter closed shape that I could create with the grid. After a lot of trial and error I eventually came up this:

[image: attempt to find the greatest perimeter polygon]

If the dot coordinates are defined by $(x,y)$ and the bottom left node is defined as $(1,1)$ then the polygon in the picture directly above can be defined by the connected nodes $(1,10)\rightarrow (1,9)\rightarrow (2,9)\rightarrow (1,8)\rightarrow (3,9)\rightarrow (1,7)\rightarrow (4,9)\rightarrow (1,6)\rightarrow (5,9)\rightarrow (1,5)\rightarrow
(6,9)\rightarrow (1,4)\rightarrow
(7,9)\rightarrow (1,3)\rightarrow
(8,9)\rightarrow (1,2)\rightarrow (9,9)\rightarrow (1,1)\rightarrow (9,8)\rightarrow (2,1)\rightarrow (9,7)\rightarrow (3,1)\rightarrow 
(9,6)\rightarrow (4,1)\rightarrow 
(9,5)\rightarrow (5,1)\rightarrow 
(9,4)\rightarrow (6,1)\rightarrow
(9,3)\rightarrow (7,1)\rightarrow 
(9,2)\rightarrow (8,1)\rightarrow
(10,1)\rightarrow (10,10)\rightarrow
(1,10)$

This polygon has a polygon has a perimeter of $\approx 202.32\space units$

The exact amount is presented by the following expression $$20+8\sqrt{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{15}\sqrt{\lceil\frac{n^2}{2}}\rceil$$

At the time I came up with this I thought that this wasn't the absolute maximum, but It was very close to the maximum and I was quite satisfied with result.

This problem has never completely left my mind and much later I realized that I could do a lot better. The polygon directly below is my best thus far.

[image: a better attempt to find the greatest perimeter polygon]

This is defined by the connected points $(1,10)\rightarrow  (1,9)\rightarrow (2,9)\rightarrow (1,8)\rightarrow
(3,9)\rightarrow (2,8)\rightarrow
(4,9)\rightarrow (1,7)\rightarrow
(3,8)\rightarrow (2,7)\rightarrow
(5,9)\rightarrow (1,6)\rightarrow
(4,8)\rightarrow (3,7)\rightarrow
(6,9)\rightarrow (2,6)\rightarrow
(5,8)\rightarrow (1,5)\rightarrow
(4,7)\rightarrow (3,6)\rightarrow
(7,9)\rightarrow (2,5)\rightarrow
(6,8)\rightarrow (1,4)\rightarrow
(5,7)\rightarrow (4,6)\rightarrow
(8,9)\rightarrow (3,5)\rightarrow
(7,8)\rightarrow (2,4)\rightarrow
(6,7)\rightarrow (1,3)\rightarrow
(5,6)\rightarrow (4,5)\rightarrow
(9,9)\rightarrow (3,4)\rightarrow
(8,8)\rightarrow (2,3)\rightarrow
(7,7)\rightarrow (1,2)\rightarrow
(6,6)\rightarrow (5,5)\rightarrow
(9,8)\rightarrow (4,4)\rightarrow
(8,7)\rightarrow (3,3)\rightarrow
(7,6)\rightarrow (2,2)\rightarrow
(6,5)\rightarrow (1,1)\rightarrow
(5,4)\rightarrow (4,3)\rightarrow
(9,7)\rightarrow (3,2)\rightarrow
(8,6)\rightarrow (2,1)\rightarrow
(7,5)\rightarrow (6,4)\rightarrow
(9,6)\rightarrow (5,3)\rightarrow
(8,5)\rightarrow (4,2)\rightarrow
(7,4)\rightarrow (3,1)\rightarrow
(6,3)\rightarrow (5,2)\rightarrow
(9,5)\rightarrow (4,1)\rightarrow
(8,4)\rightarrow (7,3)\rightarrow
(9,4)\rightarrow (6,2)\rightarrow
(8,3)\rightarrow (5,1)\rightarrow
(7,2)\rightarrow (6,1)\rightarrow
(9,3)\rightarrow (7,1)\rightarrow
(9,2)\rightarrow (8,1)\rightarrow
(10,1)\rightarrow (10,10)\rightarrow
(1,10)$

This polygon has a perimeter of $\approx 355.06 \space units$

The exact amount is presented by the following expression
$$122+16\sqrt{2}+7\sqrt{5}+13\sqrt{13}+17\sqrt{41}+5\sqrt{61}$$

**Question:** Can we find and prove a maximum for the ten by ten grid? If so can we generalize this strategy to find the maximum for the $N$ x $N$ grid?

Just for clarification on the rules, the only two requirements is that the line segment end points must be on the nodes whose coordinates are positive integers (within  the square) and the shape must be closed. A shape like the one shown in the picture below is allowed, however only the distances between the intersection points are counted toward the perimeter of the shape.

[image: rules clarification]

Comment: It appears there is an implicit rule that each peg is used once. (I guess otherwise this would be trivial). Do you have a best solution for any small grid?

Comment: @Radost There isn't a limit on how many lines can be used on a peg however doing so might split one shape into multiple and thus reducing the perimeter (and using any pegs zero times would be inefficient). While trivial the maximum for the 2x2 grid is $4$ and maximum for the 3x3 grid is $8+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what happens when a curve crosses itself (like a figure 8), but I think that the problem, when restricted to embedded curves (i.e., those where all vertices have degree at most 2, and where the interiors of any two distinct edges are disjoint) is still plenty interesting.

Comment: @JohnHughes if there is a figure eight pattern this would be two different closed regions so you would get two numbers on the geoboard for perimeters of polygons (one for each hole in the eight). Although I wouldn't be surprised if allowing intersections doesn't provide any advantage toward obtaining the largest perimeter.

Comment: I answered a similar question at MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247754/rule-for-finding-largest-possible-perimeter/248300#248300. You can similarly improve the 355.06 number -- e.g. by connecting the upper right corner to the two points at distance $\sqrt{65}$, and other corresponding adjustments, which would increase the perimeter by $2\sqrt{65}+2\sqrt{50}-\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{2}-1$.

Comment: If you will not receive a complete answer here, there is one more option. [Erich Friedman](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/index.html) for more than twenty years maintains [Math Magic](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/archive.html), a web site devoted to original mathematical recreations. 
He wrote, “if you have a math puzzle, discovery, or observation, please e-mail me (at efriedma@stetson.edu) about it”. I solved several of his problems when I was younger and I think he may be interested in yours.

Comment: So you can propose it to him as a problem of the month and then experienced solvers will attack it for a month. PS. If you’ll decide to e-mail Erich Friedman, you can give him my regards and say that I recommended you to propose the problem to him . :-)

Comment: @Steve Kass I can see how your answer is a little better than Matt's but what if you made a few more zig-zags on the top and right? It appears that the longer lines there would out-weigh the shortening of lines in the middle up to some point which might be the middle of the top or right. I can't tell.

Comment: For $n=4$, optimal is $8+4\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{5} \approx 22.60$.  For $n=5$, the solution with perimeter 44.43 linked by @MattF. is optimal.  For $n=10$, an upper bound from TSP (ignoring crossings) is 760.73.

Comment: For $n=6$, optimal is $23+6\sqrt{2}+5\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{10}+6\sqrt{13} +2\sqrt{17} \approx 78.87$.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit longer than Matt’s polygon.

[Improved based on Matt’s comment to this answer.]

[image]

{1, 10}, {1, 8}, {2, 8}, {4, 9}, {1, 7}, {3, 8}, {2, 7}, {5, 9}, {1,6}, {4, 8}, {3, 7}, {6, 9}, {2, 6}, {5, 8}, {1, 5}, {4, 7}, {3, 6},{7, 9}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {1, 4}, {5, 7}, {4, 6}, {8, 9}, {3, 5}, {7,8}, {2, 4}, {6, 7}, {1, 3}, {5, 6}, {4, 5}, {9, 9}, {3, 4}, {8, 8},{2, 3}, {7, 7}, {1, 2}, {6, 6}, {5, 5}, {9, 8}, {4, 4}, {8, 7}, {3,3}, {7, 6}, {2, 2}, {6, 5}, {1, 1}, {5, 4}, {4, 3}, {9, 7}, {3, 2},{8, 6}, {2, 1}, {7, 5}, {6, 4}, {9, 6}, {5, 3}, {8, 5}, {4, 2}, {7,4}, {3, 1}, {6, 3}, {9, 5}, {5, 2}, {8, 4}, {4, 1}, {7, 3}, {6, 2},{9, 4}, {5, 1}, {8, 3}, {7, 2}, {6, 1}, {8, 2}, {7, 1}, {8, 1}, {10,1}, {10, 8}, {9, 2}, {10, 9}, {9, 3}, {10, 10}, {3, 9}, {9, 10}, {2,9}, {8, 10}, {1, 10}

Length $32 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{5}+15 \sqrt{13}+4 \sqrt{37}+16 \sqrt{41}+5 \sqrt{61}+125\approx 396.87859$.

Comment: You can make four replacements of $\sqrt{37}+\sqrt{26}$ with $\sqrt{50}+\sqrt{37}$ at the top right corner and its neighbors. This replaces $12\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{26}$ in the sum with $32\sqrt{2}$, for an increase of 7.88.

Comment: Nice! I’ll edit my answer to include your improvement.

Answer (score 4):

The following plausibly-but-not-necessarily optimal modification of the above gives a perimeter of $383.61$, as

$126+22\sqrt{2}+5\sqrt{5}+16\sqrt{13}+16\sqrt{41}+5\sqrt{61}+2\sqrt{65}:$

[image]

$(1,10) - (1,9) - (1,8) - (3,9) - (2,8) - (4,9) - (1,7) - (3,8) - (2,7) - (5,9) - (1,6) - (4,8) - (3,7) - (6,9) - (2,6) - (5,8) - (1,5) - (4,7) - (3,6) - (7,9) - (2,5) - (6,8) - (1,4) - (5,7) - (4,6) - (8,9) - (3,5) - (7,8) - (2,4) - (6,7) - (1,3) - (5,6) - (4,5) - (9,9) - (3,4) - (8,8) - (2,3) - (7,7) - (1,2) - (6,6) - (5,5) - (9,8) - (4,4) - (8,7) - (3,3) - (7,6) - (2,2) - (6,5) - (1,1) - (5,4) - (4,3) - (9,7) - (3,2) - (8,6) - (2,1) - (7,5) - (6,4) - (9,6) - (5,3) - (8,5) - (4,2) - (7,4) - (3,1) - (6,3) - (9,5) - (5,2) - (8,4) - (4,1) - (7,3) - (6,2) - (9,4) - (5,1) - (8,3) - (7,2) - (9,3) - (6,1) - (8,2) - (7,1) - (8,1) - (10,1) - (10,9) - (9,2) - (10,10) - (2,9) - (9,10) - (1,10)  $